# Mapping AWS route 53 recordset to godaddy

Tags: amazon-route53

I'm new to Amazon.
My client hosted their website `www.domain.com` at `godaddy` and
they have created the aws ec2 instance and running their `Django` apps in this instance.

Now they wants to use this instance for subdomain. say www.subdomain.domain.com

So I have created a record set in aws route 53 by following procedure.

1. Created Recordset  A pointing to elastic IP
2. Created Nameserver (NS)

Finally added this recordset into godaddy dns files. Still I'm not able to access this subdomain. Please can anyone help here.

Comment: You will need to be much more specific than simply *"I'm not able to access this subdomain."*  What happens when you try?  *"2. Created Nameserver (NS)"* What does that mean, where did you do this, what does it point to, and why do you think that step would that be necessary?

Answer (score 0):

Are you managing DNS through AWS?

If so..

- You need to create a DNS Zone for that domain.
- Add the records or import the ZONE file
- Take the Name Server records from AWS
- Go to the domain registrar(assuming you manage this also), in this case GoDaddy!
- Point the Name Server records from AWS to GoDaddy!